# Need help investigating thread dump from NetBeans RCP Application freeze

Tags: netbeans-platform, jstack

I have a NetBeans RCP based application which, apparently only on some PCs and only sometimes, just freezes itself after opening a new TopComponent. Honestly I never looked at a JVM thread dump, but I really have no other clue about what could be happening. Unfortunately, I can't tell whether the thread dump file is complete or not, since jstack produces the following exception when trying to generate the dump:

```
Attaching to core c:\bas.txt from executable 8836, please wait...
Error attaching to core file: Windbg Error: OpenDumpFile failed!
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Windbg Error: OpenDumpFile failed!
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.windbg.WindbgDebuggerLocal.attach0(Native Method)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.windbg.WindbgDebuggerLocal.attach(WindbgDebuggerLocal.java:160)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attachDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:673)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebuggerWin32(HotSpotAgent.java:569)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:335)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:304)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:156)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:191)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
```

So I managed to start my RCP application with a console window, and pressed CTRL+break when it hanged. As said I can't be sure whether it's complete or not, since the console window could have had more lines that were removed from the buffer.

Anyway, this is the link to the dump file (I manually added the first lines in order to open it in Thread Dump Analyzer):

http://pastebin.com/1M5T85i5

Can someone help me understanding this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a deadlock. The easiest way to diagnose deadlock is to attach to the Java program using JConsole (included with the JDK) and use the Detect Deadlock function.

1. Run JAVA_HOME/bin/jconsole
2. Select the hung process and click Connect
3. If you get a warning about a secure connection, just click the insecure button.
4. Select the Threads tab and click Detect Deadlock
5. If there is a deadlock, the GUI will highlight the participating threads.
6. You can then inspect the call stacks of the locked threads and begin to reason about which locks are causing the deadlock.